# aid organizations will struggle to rally

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Does "aid organizations will struggle to **rally**" mean "aid organizations will struggle to "**convene and recruit aid workers**"?

---

Although there are some reports of refugees testing positive for the virus, as of mid-April, there are no known COVID-19 outbreaks in major refugee camps, according to advocates and responders contacted by Nature. But many aid groups fear that it is only a matter of time before the disease strikes. According to advocacy groups, host nations have been slow to enforce preventative measures. And experts fear that **aid organizations will struggle to rally** and respond.

Source:  Nature    24 APRIL 2020
https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-01219-6

Comment: How did you get from [rally](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rally) to *convene and recruit aid workers*? While rally *might* involve that, that's only a very small part of what it can mean. It's far more likely that *rally* here means "RECOVER, REBOUND // *rallied* briefly from his illness."

Comment: Thank you.    Dictionaries say "rally" means "to gather and organize or inspire anew." Which appears to be suitable here.

Comment: The word has many different senses. It will not always mean one as opposed to all of the others. You have to put it into context. If I say *box*, I can mean either a package, or I can mean an action where I hit someone else. (And those are only two of the possible meanings.) You can't know just by looking at *box* how I'm using it.